# Libgdx Box2d pixel to meter scaling

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I am trying to make a game with Box2d. My problem is the scaling between the pixels and the meters. I painted a ship with a size of about 500px * 200px. This ship would be 1.5m high in real. So I calculated my PPM with 330. My background is 8000px * 1500px big. Thats also the world size. Now the world and the ship is good deiplayed but as always I am not able to scale the whole thign right, that also Box2d elemts are right scaled...

EDIT:

Now I forget about pixels and do everything in meters. Although I donWt get why the most people use this PPM when its completely unnecessary. So can you look at my code and tell me if I understand it right and did it right?  It works perfect ;)

```
package com.timelab.space;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;


public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
private Space g;
//Textures
private Texture background;
private Texture ship;

//Parameters
private int worldHeight = 10;//Meters
private int worldWidth = 53;//Meters fitting to the texutrebackground

//Camera
private OrthographicCamera camera;

//Box2D
private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer b2ddr;
private Body player;


public PlayScreen(Space pgame) {
    g = pgame;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.update();

    System.out.print("Created "+this.getClass().getSimpleName());
}

@Override
public void show() {
    background = g.getAssets().manager.get("Textures/space.png",Texture.class);
    ship = g.getAssets().manager.get("Textures/ship.png",Texture.class);

    //Box2D
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,0), false);
    b2ddr = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    player = createPlayer();
}

private void update(float delta) {
    //Camera
    camera.position.add(0,0,0);
    //Box2d
    world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    this.update(delta);

    //camera
    g.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    camera.update();

    g.batch.begin();
    g.batch.draw(background,0,0,worldWidth,worldHeight);
    g.batch.draw(ship,player.getPosition().x-3.7f/2,player.getPosition().y-1.5f/2,3.7f,1.5f);
    g.batch.end();

    //box2d
    b2ddr.render(world, camera.combined);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportHeight = worldHeight;
    camera.viewportWidth = (worldHeight * ((float)width/(float)height));
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
    camera.update();
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    b2ddr.dispose();
}

public Body createPlayer() {
    Body body;
    //Physical body definition
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.position.set(0,0);
    def.fixedRotation = true;

    //Add the body to the world
    body = world.createBody(def);

    //Add a shape
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(3.7f/2, 1.5f/2);
    body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);

    //disposing
    shape.dispose();

    return body;
}
}
```

Comment: Ditch that PPM stuff. Those things you call pixels only exist in your imagination and are making your code unreadable and unmanageable. See also: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/pixels.

Comment: ok I would like to not think in pixels but for example you have differnet phones with a different amount of pixels.. your graphics are made out of them and need to be scaled down for the actual device. your logic just needs meters and stuff like that but the problem is that you have to combined the pixel and each mobile to your logic wihtout pixels...

Comment: I also cant see the differnce between the psoted code and mine bith working in the same way with PPM

Comment: You might want to actually read the post i referred to.

Comment: just read the whole post... xD

Comment: I made an edit can someone check this?

Comment: Looks fine. Glad you solved it.

Comment: thanks but why did some people use PPM?

Comment: probably ignorance